# how to manage chinese language when sending it in request on web service.

Tags: android, web-services, multilingual

when sending a request on web service from android, it become question marks(?) on web side.

```
{CategoryId=5; CategoryName=開胃; CategoryDesc = 開胃; }
```

but in app it display like &#38283,&#32963

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when send your string to server

```
String encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(yourString, "UTF-8");
```

when get your string from server

```
String decodedString = URLDecoder.decode(yourString, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering bit late but hope it will help someone else. I faced the same issue and resolved by setting `CharacterSet` to `utf-8` and `Content-Type` to `application/json` in my case. You can select other content types as per your requirement. See below

```
StringEntity s = new StringEntity(data.toString(), "utf-8");
s.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
```

Below is the complete method.

```
public static String doPost(JSONObject data, String url)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, TimeoutException, ApiException {

    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeoutConnection = 30000; // 30 Seconds
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
            timeoutConnection);

    int timeoutSocket = 50000;
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + addAuthHeader());

    Log.d("TAG", "Data ==> " + data.toString());

    StringEntity s = new StringEntity(data.toString(), "utf-8");
    s.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

    httppost.setEntity(s);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String status = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);


    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        status = "ApiError";
        throw new ApiException();           
    }           

    Log.d("TAG", "Response String ====== " + status);

    return status;
}
```